# How to import HTML file in CKEditor 4 with styles written in external CSS file in React project?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to open HTML file in CKEditor to edit. I am able to get the content with in-line CSS, but it is missing css formatting coming from the external .CSS file.

I have tried using stylesheetparser plugin, but I am still missing something. here is my current code:

```
function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState(html);

  return (
    <div>
      <CKEditor
      initData = {htmlContent}
      config={{
        extraPlugins: 'stylesheetparser',
        contentsCss:'./converted-style.css'
      }}
      />
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: Issue was with the path of css. CSS file should be in the public folder while working with react.